# How can we take advantage of moveTo( ) HTML5 method?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

please I am a little confused so I need your help .

My question is how can we take advantage of moveTo() html5 method ?

for example I found this example on stackOverflow

```
function drawSmile(ctx, x, y, faceRadius, eyeRadius) {
    ctx.save();               // save 
    ctx.fillStyle = '#FF6';   // face style : fill color is yellow
    ctx.translate(x, y);      // now (x,y) is the (0,0) of the canvas.
    ctx.beginPath();          // path for the face
    ctx.arc(0, 0, faceRadius, 0, 6.28);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.fillStyle = '#000';  // eye style : fill color is black
    ctx.beginPath();         // path for the two eyes
    ctx.arc(faceRadius / 2, - faceRadius /3, eyeRadius, 0, 6.28);
    ctx.moveTo(-faceRadius / 2, - faceRadius / 3); // sub path for second eye
    ctx.arc(-faceRadius / 2, - faceRadius / 3, eyeRadius, 0, 6.28);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.restore(); // context is just like before entering drawSmile now.
}
drawSmile(c, 200,200, 60, 12);
```

but when I removed the line number 11 in the code which uses the moveTo method no thing changed!!!!.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `moveTo()` HTML5 method lets you to move your (0,0) origin to another point in the space.

Here you have and example. To draw some kind of triangle:

[image]

```
// first part of the path
ctx.moveTo(20,20);
ctx.lineTo(100, 100); 
ctx.lineTo(100,0);

// second part of the path
ctx.moveTo(120,20);
ctx.lineTo(200, 100); 
ctx.lineTo(200,0);

// indicate stroke color + draw the path
ctx.strokeStyle = "#0000FF";
ctx.stroke();
```

In this example we simply called `moveTo(x, y)` after drawing the first part of the path (the shape on the left). Then, we only called  `stroke()` once to draw the whole path.

Comment: thanx , but I want to understand why it does not work in my example above , I changed its values in my example but no thing changed .

Comment: Why do you say that it is not working?
[Online demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hr65N/1/)

Comment: I tried that ?? I replaced the line number 11 in the code ctx.moveTo(-faceRadius / 2, - faceRadius / 3); with this line ctx.moveTo(100, 100); and no thing changed ???

Comment: If you change that values the eyes are moved! Have you clicked on the update button?

Comment: thanx for your efforts m.@Rafa Romero ,  I saved  the changes and I loaded the page agin and again but no thing changed.